# WSPBuilder cannot find my assembly

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss, wss, sharepoint-2010, wspbuilder

I am using WSPBuilder on Visual Studio 2010 to create a feature with a feature receiver assembly for SharePoint 2010. When I try to build the WSP using WSP Builder I get this message in the output window:

```
The assembly MyAssembly.dll is unmanaged. The assembly will be excluded from the WSP package!
The defined Project Assembly seems not to be a valid assembly!
Solution compatibility: SharePoint 2010
```

The resulting WSP that gets built does not contain my DLL.

My DLL is strongly named, and I cant think of any other obvious reasons why this is happening.
Any idea why WSPBuilder is not able to package my assembly in the WSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh... Found the answer. My code was getting compiled against .Net Framework 4.0. Changed it to .Net Framework 3.5 and Voila! WSP gets built without any problems...